CSRF Token Mismatch Error in Laravel with React Frontend Using Axios
I'm developing a web application with a React frontend and a Laravel backend. I am trying to implement authentication, but I am encountering a CSRF token mismatch error when making a POST request to the /login endpoint.
Setup
Frontend: React
Backend: Laravel
HTTP Client: Axios
Development Environment:
Frontend: http://localhost:3000
Backend: http://localhost:8000\
Axios Configuration
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL,
  withCredentials: true, // Include credentials (cookies) with requests
});

export default axiosClient;

Login Function
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axiosClient from './axiosClient'; // Import your axios instance

const onSubmit = async (values) => {
  try {
    // Fetch CSRF cookie
    await axiosClient.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

    // Send login request
    const response = await axiosClient.post('/login', values);

    // Handle successful login
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      navigate('/'); // Redirect to dashboard after successful login
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login Error:", error);
    if (error.response) {
      console.error("Error Data:", error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.error("No Response Received:", error.request);
    } else {
      console.error("Error Message:", error.message);
    }
  }
};

Network Request Details
GET /sanctum/csrf-cookie: Successfully fetches the CSRF token and sets it in cookies.
POST /login: Results in a 419 status code with a "CSRF token mismatch" error.
Error Message
{
  "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
  "file": "/path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
  "line": 492
}

What I've Tried:

Verified that the CSRF token is correctly received and set in cookies.
Ensured Axios is configured to send credentials (withCredentials: true).
Checked that the CSRF token is included in the request headers.
Reviewed Laravel session and CORS configuration.
Ensured the order of middleware in Laravel is correct.

Despite these efforts, I am still receiving the CSRF token mismatch error.
Any insights or suggestions on what I might be missing or additional steps to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.`

"Reviewed Laravel session and CORS configuration"... could you please [edit] your question to include the CORS and cookie configurations? You need Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true and Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000 (NOT *)
